# Correct term for an automatically generated method or variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminology

Rails makes heavy use of automatically generating various methods and variables. In my own private notes I refer to these as `dynamic methods`, but what is the official name for these things?

**Some examples of these `dynamic methods`:**

Creating a relationship like this:

```
class Carriage < ActiveRecord::Base
    # attrs: id, wheels, spare
    has_one :horse
end
class Horse < ActiveRecord::Base
    # attrs: id, carriage_id, name
    belongs_to :carriage
end
```

Means you can do this:

```
> Carriage.create(wheels: 2).create_horse(name: "Fledge")
```

In that example, `create_horse` would be the `dynamic method`

**Another example:**

If I were to create a model method to add a wheel to a `Carriage`:

```
class Carriage < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.wheels = wheels + 1 if spare == true 
end
```

I have access to an intance's attributes, each in its own `dynamic` variable: `wheels` and `spare`. `id` is scoped to the method as well. I call these `dynamic` variables, but what's their official name?

Comment: If there were an official name I would expect to find them in the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference), but I don't see them called anything there except methods

Comment: Personally, I refer to them as 'magic methods', because Rails creates them for you 'like magic', but that's... probably not standard, let's say.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that those methods are generated at runtime by [Ruby metaprogramming](http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/).

Look at [the source here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/singular_association.rb).

```
# Defines the (build|create)_association methods for belongs_to or has_one association

def self.define_constructors(mixin, name)
  mixin.class_eval <<-CODE, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def build_#{name}(*args, &block)
      association(:#{name}).build(*args, &block)
    end

    def create_#{name}(*args, &block)
      association(:#{name}).create(*args, &block)
    end

    def create_#{name}!(*args, &block)
      association(:#{name}).create!(*args, &block)
    end
  CODE
end
```

Basically, the huge template between `<<-CODE, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1` and `CODE` is getting evaled at runtime to generate the following methods:

- `build_horse`
- `create_horse`
- `create_horse!`

So when you call them, they are in no way different that the other methods you have defined yourself on the `Carriage` class.

Comment: Very interesting, but they don't seem to have a name then. Does `define_constructors` mean they're called `constructors` maybe?

Comment: Not at all, they are called constructors because they build objects, but that doesn't convey the meaning of being a result of metaprogramming :)